# Is sum or matrix multiplication faster?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, sum, matrix-multiplication

I have a very simple question, is using `sum` or matrix multiplication faster to sum a large vector? More precisely, here an example of problem I am trying to speed up:

```
d <- 1000
X <- matrix(rnorm(d^2), nrow = d)
y <- rnorm(d)

## Solution 1
sum(X%*%y)
## Solution 2
rep(1, d)%*%(X%*%y)
```

I have tried testing the two with `system.time()`, but the times jump around each other and I can't get a fix on it. The times are very similar so this question has passed from practical to just inquisitive. Perhaps they are exactly the same time (seems unlikely).

Here's the function I've written to test it:

```
testSum <- function(d, its){
  X <- matrix(rnorm(d^2), nrow=d)
  y <- rnorm(d)

  store <- matrix(NA, nrow = its, ncol = 3)
  store2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = its, ncol = 3)

  for(i in 1:its) store[i, ] <- system.time(sum(X%*%y))[1:3]
  for(i in 1:its) store2[i, ] <- system.time(rep(1, d)%*%(X%*%y))[1:3]

  return(list(sumF = mean(store[, 1]),
              MM = mean(store2[, 1])))
}

testSum(1000, 100)
```

And the output always looks something like this:

```
$sumF
[1] 0.01021

$MM
[1] 0.01028
```

Where the top is using sum and the bottom is using matrix multiplication. Any hints, suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: The time differences may be more apparent in the asymptotic limit. I would try taking `d` larger if you can't see an apparent difference, and if you still don't see much difference then the only conclusion you can draw is that they're about equal :)

Comment: You need to use [microbenchmark](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html#microbenchmarking)..

Comment: I did that, @drglove, until I got too lazy for it to last any longer. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple thing to try is using a larger vector.

#### Using a million.

```
library(microbenchmark)

A <- rnorm(1000000)
B <- rep(1, 1000000)

system.time(sum(A))
user  system elapsed
0.012   0.000   0.01

system.time(B %*% A)
user  system elapsed
0.044   0.000   0.04

microbenchmark(sum(A), B%*%A)
Unit: microseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 sum(A)  899.735  953.361 1021.005 1021.415 1081.348 1885.857   100
B %*% A 2846.589 2946.579 3063.001 2993.341 3132.779 4498.773   100
```

#### Using 10 million.

```
library(microbenchmark)

A <- rnorm(10000000)
B <- rep(1, 10000000)

system.time(sum(A))
user  system elapsed
0.012   0.000   0.011

system.time(B %*% A)
user  system elapsed
0.044   0.000   0.044

microbenchmark(sum(A), B%*%A)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 sum(A)  8.993579  9.294605  9.975156  9.729226 10.22477 14.29411   100
B %*% A 32.716323 33.818031 35.586381 35.966695 36.86165 41.13194   100
```

On my machine sum is ~4 times faster.

NOTE: I precomputed the vectors instead of multiplying vector and matrix to get a vector. Also precomputed the vector of ones to make the comparison more fair.

Comment: Ah, I think this is the best way to do this! I was trying to use a large dimensional matrix and my computer was very unhappy with that. Surprised the difference is so large, however.

Comment: Ya, I feel that in order to compare two fast operations you would need to remove the more complex procedures (matrix multiplication) common to both of them. Otherwise the operations being compared will become dwarfed by them. Also added benchmarks to my answer (same as in @jeremycg answer) showing the difference.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in the `microbenchmark` package, an easy way to time small functions a lot of times:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sum(X%*%y),rep(1, d)%*%(X%*%y))
```

gives me:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
            sum(X %*% y) 10.01472 10.52420 14.25944 11.11969 13.67134 74.26345   100
 rep(1, d) %*% (X %*% y) 10.13382 10.55444 12.99910 10.87629 12.95769 50.38268   100
```

So on my (slow) laptop, they are more or less the same.